# Why is <input type=date /> being selected after setting user-select to none?

Tags: html, css

I have this following HTML in which I have set the CSS `user-select` property to `none`. For some reason, it's still being selected. Can you tell me why this is happening and how to avoid it?

```css
input::-webkit-datetime-edit { 
    user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<input type='date' />
```

I have tried selecting the `input` element itself and the placeholder of the `input`.

```css
input { 
    user-select: none;
}
```

```css
input::placeholder { 
    user-select: none;
}
```

But that also doesn't work. When I focus upon the input, it still selects one of the three things (the day, the month, or the year), as shown in the below photographs.

[Image on immediate focus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFFCb.png)

[Image after selecting a date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjCbi.png)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to disable the input? why not just use the `disabled` attribute if that's the case. Note that if the input is `disabled` it will not be submitted. Use wisely!

Comment: No, I'm trying to make sure that you can't select any part of the date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is required for **usability**. Without a visual clue as to what part of the date you are about to enter - especially using the keyboard - it is not very usable.

You can tab to the date field and through the date parts with the keyboard, but without having the date part highlighted, you don't know whether the *day*, *month* or *year* has focus so you don't know what you are about to enter.

Comment: So, there is no possible way to stop the selection?

Comment: @SafwanSamsudeen No, none that I have ever come across anyway. But more importantly you shouldn't be trying to do this if you want your input to be usable :) Why do you want to stop the selection showing? There might be something else you could do.

Comment: No, I don't want the `dd/mm/yyyy` to show up at all. I can hide the placeholder - or what ever the `dd/mm/yyyy` is called  - with CSS and show it after the user chooses a value using jQuery. But, as soon as I focus upon the `input`, a part of the `dd/mm/yyyy` is shown. Thanks for the answer anyway.

Comment: @SafwanSamsudeen If you don't want the `dd/mm/yyyy` to appear (you only mentioned the select highlight in your question) and you are willing to use a non-CSS option, then instead of using the default date input you could use [jQuery DatePicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) - it works differently in thatit is a single input with no separate date parts so the user can enter anything, but it will give you the appearance you are looking for!

Comment: I had known about the jQuery DatePicker, it's just that it looks really ugly.

Comment: @SafwanSamsudeen Yes it does by default but you can style it to change the look, even the calendar popup. A javascript/jQuery option is the only alternative I can think of to give you the appearance you want so if might be worth a look if you really need what you are trying to do.